# Как использовать одну функцию на много элементов?

Tags: javascript

Друзья!)
Первый раз тут, с почином меня, что называется! И не сказать драсьте тут у вас(

Есть [вот такой код](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmbQYJ), мне нужно дизеблить каждый input отдельно, как это сделать?

p.s. обещаю учить script. уже начала!)

```js
var btnChange = document.querySelector('.change');
var btnSave = document.querySelector('.save');
var formGroup = document.querySelector('.form__group');

function setFormStateDisabled(isDisabled) {
  btnChange.classList.toggle('hidden', !isDisabled);
  btnSave.classList.toggle('hidden', isDisabled);
  if (isDisabled) {
    formGroup.setAttribute('disabled', isDisabled);
  } else {
    formGroup.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

```css
.data{
    max-width: 610px;
}

.form__wrap{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.form__group{
  display: flex;
}

.hidden{  display:none;}
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="data">
  <h2 class="data__heading">Личные данные</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__wrap">
      <fieldset class="form__group" disabled>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Фамилия">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Отчество">
      </fieldset>
      
      <button type=button class="change" onclick="setFormStateDisabled(false)">Изменить</button>
      <button type=button class="save hidden" onclick="setFormStateDisabled(true)">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Что есть "функционал изменения"? Вешать дизейбл не на филдсет, а на инпуты? или о чем речь?

Comment: Да, точно! Нужно каждый инпут менять и сохранять!

Comment: не очень понятно зачем нужно инпуты дизейблить, с какой целью? В каком формате вам нужны данные инпутов? Если сохранить так что бы раз и навсегда, то это надо данные на сервер отправлять, это немного за пределами "изучения js", если просто запомнить, то опять же, в каком формате, для чего эти данные планируется использовать?

Comment: С сохранением пропустим вопрос, он плавающий у меня в голове.

А инпуты могут быть уже с данными, которые есть в ЛК, т.е. если фамилия поменялась, например, её нужно изменить. Или адрес доставки старый сменить на новый. Как-то так!)

Comment: ну, это опять же вопрос к серверу ... вы конечно можете хранить эти данные где-то в рамках браузера (куки, сторейдж, ...), но пользы от этого особо нет (это узконаправленный вариант хранения данных и использовать его можно только если есть четкое понимание зачем это делается, тут он вроде как не подходит). То есть де факто вам все равно нужна серверная часть кода, что бы "хранить данные" или же я чего-то не понимаю ...

Comment: Да, вы правильно меня понимаете! Вопрос такой в итоге - как мне дизеблить каждый инпут отдельно? Или может я чего-то не понимаю?)

Comment: Зачем вам дизейблить каждый в отдельности, если дизейбл филдсета вам дает тот же эффект?) Нужно было бы дизейблить отдельные инпуты - другой разговор, а так это выглядит бессмысленно ...

Comment: Ну а если много таких форм? Для каждого же не писать свой код)))

Comment: во, другой разговор ))))

Comment: Аааа, код не тот, который будет в итоге, сглупила. инпуты не будут в филдсете)))

Answer (score 0):

Итак, давайте просто опишу вам примерный принцип работы этого кода чтобы вы понимали что и как происходит

У вас есть 3 input'a, они помещены в общую группу под названием **form__group:**

```
 <fieldset class="form__group" disabled>
```

Обратите внимание на слово disabled, этот параметр запрещает редактирование всего того что находится внутри этого контейнера, т.е. input'ов

Так же у вас имеется 2 кнопки:

```
  <button type=button class="change" onclick="setFormStateDisabled(false)">Изменить</button>
  <button type=button class="save hidden" onclick="setFormStateDisabled(true)">Сохранить</button>
```

И у одной из кнопок обратите внимание на наличие класса hidden, этот класс в стилях описан как **display:none**, т.е. все что имеет этот класс будет из страницы скрыто, в нашем случае одна из кнопок имеет этот класс.

Так же у кнопок есть параметр onclick, у обоих кнопок вызывается одна и та же js функция под названием **setFormStateDisabled**, но передаются ей разные данные, в одном случае **true**, в другом **false**, для чего это сделано? для того чтобы разные кнопки делали разные вещи, т.е. чтобы разрешали/запрещали редактирование полей и скрывали сами себя ставя себе класс hidden, но при этом убирая этот самый класс у второй кнопки, таким образом получая подмену кнопок

Теперь про js

```
var btnChange = document.querySelector('.change'); //ищем кнопку с классом change (она у нас одна, изменить которая) и "запоминаем" ее как btnChange
var btnSave = document.querySelector('.save'); //ищем кнопку с классом save (сохранить) и "запоминаем" ее как btnSave
var formGroup = document.querySelector('.form__group'); //ищем что-нибудь с классом form__group, в нашем случае это группа input'ов
```

Далее начинается функция setFormStateDisabled, то что в нее передается (true или false) внутри функции названо как "isDisabled"

```
//в этом куске происходит "обмен" классом hidden, тем самым одна кнопка прячется, а другая появляется
btnChange.classList.toggle('hidden', !isDisabled);
btnSave.classList.toggle('hidden', isDisabled);
```

Ну а тут сам процесс "блокировки/разблокировки" группы input'ов (прячется или наоборот появляется слово disabled у элемента с классом form__group) в зависимости от того что передано функции (переменная isDisabled, возможные значения true или false)

```
if (isDisabled) { //если передано true
    formGroup.setAttribute('disabled', isDisabled);
} else { //если передано false
    formGroup.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Ну а как сделать то что вам необходимо - догадаться не трудно, именуем необходимый элемент классом, при нажатии на кнопку совершаем нужные действия с ним

Comment: Вот поэтому я и решила задать вопрос здесь) Это шедеврально, спасибо!)

Comment: @АйсанДемидова не используйте `disabled`. Значения из `disabled` не передаются на сервер. Лучше используйте аттрибут `readonly`

Comment: @АйсанДемидова, оооом, вейт, типа нужно было описать что делает приведенный код и .... все?) А я думал надо типа, ну не знаю .... изменить его, что бы было по задаче .... интересно девки пляшут ...

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, так по идее сначала происходит сбор данных формы, данные отправляются на сервер, инпуты дизейблятся ... спорное замечание.

Comment: Конечно, я, как любой человек, люблю готовые решения!) Но когда учишься, такие ответы крайне полезны мне, чтобы не тупить снова, не понимая как код работает.

Здесь же можно отмечать 2 ответа решениями? Я с удовольствием приму вашу помощь!) 

Не постигла культуру таких сайтов, простите!(

Comment: @АйсанДемидова, нууу, тогда конкретизируйте в вопросе словами что-то типа "как работает этот код?" ))) Я думал этот код вы сами и написали и понимаете, что и зачем там происходит, тем более, что вы четко пояснили, что проблема возникает когда несколько подобных форм на странице и это реально выглядит как проблема требующая решения (хотя наверняка это дубликат), посему я немного не понял исхода данной таски xDD

Comment: Дубликат тут js, это мне помог один товарищ с тостера.

Что-то понимаю, что-то нет. Чуть меняется задачи и я ломаюсь, поэтому такие ответы мне кажутся ценными)

Сняла пока решение, и правда, не логично)

Comment: @MedvedevDev дизейблить - не лучшее решение если форм много, да и лишнее телодвижение. Программист нужно быть чуточку ленивым))) но вмеру.

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, опять же, спорно, вы всегда должны быть уверены в том, какая последовательность событий у вас должна происходить при том или ином действии, иначе потом возникают тонны вопросов про то, почему асинхронный код отрабатывает раньше всего остального .... ни разу не использовал readonly для подобных задач, возможно я слишком стар для этой фигни xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev ни сколько не спорный вопрос. Отличие одно - из `disabled` не передаётся, из `readonly` передаётся. `readonly` через CSS легко сэмулировать состояние, как у `disabled`. А ведь возможно я просто старше вас xDD )))

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, я не против использования `readonly`, просто я не вижу смысла в "не используйте `disabled`", по сути это одно и то же, если не вдаваться в подробности табуляции и того что отправляется, а что нет, так что просто надо понимать принцип действия того и другого и "использовать с умом"

Answer (score 0):

Если не пользуетесь babel'ем данный ответ не будет являться полезным (так как не все браузеры его поддерживают), но оставлю, раз уж написал ....

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');

// Перебор всех форм с классом .form на странице
forms.forEach(form => {
  // Для того, что бы не писать инлайновые вызовы и разделить кнопки заменил onclick на data-js аттрибут
  const saveButton = form.querySelector('[data-js=save]');
  const editButton = form.querySelector('[data-js=edit]');
  const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');

  // Вешаем на каждую кнопку внутри конкретной формы соответствующий слушатель
  // Да, в рамках данной задачи можно было объединить эти функции, но на практике такое обычно невозможно, либо усложняет читаемость
  saveButton.addEventListener('click', onSave);
  editButton.addEventListener('click', onEdit);

  function onSave() {
    saveButton.classList.add('hidden');
    editButton.classList.remove('hidden');
    
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.disabled = true;
    });
  }

  function onEdit() {
    saveButton.classList.remove('hidden');
    editButton.classList.add('hidden');
    
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.disabled = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.data{
    max-width: 610px;
}

.form__wrap{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.form__group{
  display: flex;
}

.hidden{  display:none;}
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="data">
  <h2 class="data__heading">Личные данные</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__wrap">
      <fieldset class="form__group">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Фамилия" disabled>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Имя" disabled>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Отчество" disabled>
      </fieldset>
      
      <button type="button" class="change" data-js="edit">Изменить</button>
      <button type="button" class="save hidden" data-js="save">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section class="data">
  <h2 class="data__heading">Личные данные</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__wrap">
      <fieldset class="form__group">
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Фамилия" disabled>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Имя" disabled>
        <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Отчество" disabled>
      </fieldset>
      
      <button type="button" class="change" data-js="edit">Изменить</button>
      <button type="button" class="save hidden" data-js="save">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Babel установлен у меня в сборщике.Тут проблем нет.

А что конкретно свежо пахнет? Чтобы понимать вообще что происходит :D Реально только начала пытаться понять javascript.

А так, крутой код, уже эксперименты провела, всё работает как надо. На каждый инпут перевела кнопки!

Спасибо за старание и помощь!

Сейчас закончу работу и вперёд видео смотреть. А то прыг-скок с темы на тему и каша в голове!